# I can't open this midi file with my daw (ableton 11)

Tags: midi

(the midi file is in google drive. i cant open it in ableton live 11) (https://drive.google.com/file/d/15f33DGnmy94zQ8Nt-mIhxbjJJMtz_akW/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Change its name to [anything].mid.

Right now it's just called 'mid' without an extension.